# RabbitMQ in spring(not spring boot) autowire not working

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I want to integrate rabbitmq with my spring application. So,
I added following lines inside my pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then I Created a service called RabbitMessageService,

```
@Component
public class RabbitMessageService{

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

public void sendMessage(String message) {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("testExchange","testKey",message);
    }
```

}

The problem is, RabbitTemplate @Autowire annotation is not working and rabbitTemplate is getting null when I call this method from another controller.

`RabbitMessageService.sendMessage("Hello rabbit");`

What I am missing. is the pom file looks correct with this repository or I need anything else to import? There are so many repository so I am confused which one should I import? And why autowiring is giving null here?
I tried to initialize with get set but still the send method does not work(probably manually need to set connection properties but not sure how to do it)

Comment: Hey, just to make things little more clear ... what you mean by spring not spring boot ? spring boot only differ by embedded server in it... maven and java configuration using annotations can be applied on spring mvc project. please could you make the question more clear ?

Comment: I am using spring framework. Thats why I mentioned it here to be more clear.

Comment: Please take a look at this article I used something like this before and it worked and this built on Spring MVC with Hibernate and Maven project . [RabbitMQ With Srping MVC](https://medium.com/@haseeamarathunga/rabbitmq-with-spring-mvc-micro-service-architecture-b2136f8c06)

Comment: Thank you. I will try with them.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot autoconfigures the `RabbitTemplate` for you. If you are using plain vanilla Spring, you should define the `RabbitTemplate` as a bean in your `ApplicationContext`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit // Enable @RabbitListener support
public class RabbitConfig {

  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
      return new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
  }

  @Bean
  public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
      return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
      return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
  }

}
```

Comment: I am getting very confused, So many people are telling so many things. I am using spring, not the spring boot. Can you please tell me what should I do in this case?

Comment: The solution I posted is using plain vanilla Spring, not Spring Boot, you need a RabbitTemplate definition.